# Android адаптивный размер для фото

Tags: java, android

Пока делал приложение узнал и проверил на практике утверждение что нужно скачивать фото уже нужного размера для экрана, а не в том размере котором они находятся изначально.

До этого  качал фото в размере 1280х720 с firebase storage и отображал с помощью fresco. Но уже из кеша они появлялись с задержкой секунда +- К тому же нужно платить за "ненужные пиксели", и размер кеша ...

Теперь я хочу переделать все, и у меня появились вопросы.
Фото теперь будут на imgix(предварительно) и там можно скачать их указывая высоту и ширину.

**Вопрос 1**. Как я могу определить высоту и ширину для данного экрана? Пока что я написал так:

```
private int getImageW(){
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int baseW = 480;
    return (int) (baseW * density);
}

private int getImageH(){
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int baseH = 320;


    return (int) (baseH * density);
}
```

Следуя за этим постом 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507609/image-resolution-for-mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi-and-xxhdpi

В итоге размер на моем тестовом устройстве получился 1440x960 от исходного 1280х720, хотя вполне хорошо выглядит уже размер 480х320(и работает быстро).

ПС: я понимаю что все зависит от разрешений и тд, но у меня 5,5 дюймовый экран и fullHD разрешение, и не вижу никакой разницы между 1280х720 и 480х320 в 99% случаев!!

В общем как правильно найти эти значения?

**Вопрос 2**. Я специально изначально хочу скачивать фото в зависимости от экрана, а нет от размера view, потому что оно, как я думаю кеширует исходя из url, а дубликаты мне не нужны. И поэтому вопрос 2 звучит так Как мне найти высоту и ширину картинки для view, что бы потом уменьшить ее уже используя fresco(вопрос не о fresco, а о размерах)?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам подойдет решение с разными ресурсами для разных разрешений. Например: создаете файлы `integers.xml` для каждого размера экрана и в них задаете высоту и ширину. И отправлять будете данные из этих файлов.

Comment: Это не очень адаптивное решение.Ну и в любом случае нужна какая-то "формула" для расчета этих значений

Comment: Тогда нужно отталкиваться от размера ImageView. Взять его размер в пикселях и отправлять это на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге вот к чему удалось прийти:

- Пикселей в картинке должно быть не меньше чем во view которое ее отображает - иначе потеря качества неизбежна. А значит нужно запрашивать картинку по размеру view.
- Можно сократить размер иначе - изменив [формат](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer) и [качество](https://uploadcare.com/docs/uc_optimize/use_cases/#optimize).
- Можно и нужно уменьшать уже загруженные картинки до размеров view.

Пример на моем случае:

Все мои активности в портретном режиме, одна и та же картинка может отображаться  почти во всю ширину экрана и в более маленьком view (~90dp) в listView.

По этому я скачиваю картини размером во всю ширину экрана(портретную). Размер экрана можно получить так:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int w =  metrics.widthPixels;
```

Затем если надо подгоняю их под view (Я использую fresco)

```
 ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder
                .newBuilderWithSource(uri)// сборный адрес который указывает на картинку, ее размер, формат, и качество.
                .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width,height)//ширина и высота view.
                .build();
mImage.setImageRequest(request);
```

В итоге благодаря проделанным операциям удалось снизить размер файла(1280х720.webp) где то на 40% в среднем 15kb. и теперь нет никаких задержек при загрузки картинки во view(не считая холодного старта, когда картинки скачиваються на устройство, но и тут меньше секунды). При этом визуальное качество ничуть не изменилось.

Если есть еще какие-то идеи пишите.